# Referrring to movie clips using variable strings

Tags: string, flash, actionscript-2, movieclip

I want to know how to use a variable string to reference a movie clip in a hierarchy in AS2.

For example, and please forgive my newbie coding:

If my variable is defined as:

```
_root.MovieName = "Bob";
```

Then I'd like to be able to write:

```
_root.MovieName.ChildClip.gotoAndPlay("Label");
```

Where MovieName is the string "Bob" and not an actual instance called "MovieName".  So Flash looks for an instance of "Bob" and goes into the child clips from there.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The ChildClip is not a property of the MovieName.  It will be a property of the root.  Since you set _root.MovieName = "Bob", this implies that you are working with a single instance and you don't have to search for the movie with the name "Bob".  If there are multiple movies or you have to query, do the search and populate your object.  After the object is populated, then use _root.ChildClip.gotoAndPlay().

Comment: I apologize, I didn't explain very well.  Basically ChildClip is an instance INSIDE the instance named Bob.  I was just using it for illustration.  What I want Flash to do is be able to identify a movie clip's name from within a variable.  That is, if there are multiple instances, find the one named whatever MovieName has been set to, and do something to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND THE ANSWER!

In order to refer to movie clip instances using variables, first declare that variable as a string, then use the this[] handler.  Here is the code that worked for me and the page that held it:

// CREATE THE STRING
var newString:String = "movieClipInstanceName";

// ASSUMING YOU ALREADY HAVE A MOVIECLIP WITH AN INSTANCE NAME OF "movieClipInstanceName" ON STAGE,
//CHANGE THE ALPHA OF THE MOVIECLIP TO 0
this[newString].alpha = 0;

And the page:

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?327501-Converting-String-to-Movie-Clip-Instance-Name

Big thanks to everyone who pitched in to help me!

Answer (score 0):

_root actually is a reference to the "root" of the movie, which also inherits a bunch of properties, it behaves like an object, so yes, you can do things like the following:

```
trace(_root["Bob"]); //Should return the instance.
var movieName = "Bob";
trace(_root[movieName]); //Should be the same.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Vulturous.  I know how to declare variables.  What I want to know is how to dynamically access a movie clip using those variables.  I've tried all the methods listed on this page:  http://www.quip.net/blog/2006/flash/actionscript-20/reference-objects-dynamically . . . . but none of them work either.  Would be nice if I could figure out how to upload the .fla to show what's going on.